# If you can send through some more time that’d be great

Tags: meaning

Today at work I received an email and in the end my correspondant said :

> If you can send through some more time that’d be great.

I am struggling a bit to understand what it exactly means. She  always uses contractions and weird turns of phrases I never understand...

Does she means that she needs more time to do the thing I asked for ? Or does she needs me to tell her when I need the thing to be done ?

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT**

What happenned is that I asked her to perform a task ans she answered

> Great to meet with you this morning/ afternoon. I am handling urgent updates before some presentations this afternoon, but I’d like to resume in the next few days to continue reviewing your requests.

And then she added

> We can discuss this further once we finish reviewing the requirements this week and determine the estimated # of hours required to make these updates. If you can send through some more time that’d be great. Thank you!

Comment: Taken as written it sounds like she literally wants you to send her more time. Heck, there are days when I wish someone would send *me* a couple of hours, if for no other reason than to sleep a little longer on weekday mornings. Seriously, though. As a native speaker I don't know what she means. You should ask her to clarify her request.

Comment: It's not a recognized usage. We could *guess* that she wants you to send her some kind of formal authorization allowing her to spend more time on some project. But that's all it would be - a guess (i.e. - *a matter of **opinion***).

Comment: @Agathe - We will need to see the rest of the email to help you here. Her meaning may be easier to discern in that context. Please use the [edit] link to add it to your question. Without that, the question may be closed.

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot disclose that kind of info as it is confidential ...

Comment: I'm reading this as a perfectly reasonable reaction, just not one to be taken literally:  "I'd love to help you but I don't have enough hours in the day.  Can you please send me the hour it will take me to do this task for you?"