# "I hope all’s well, and absolutely. " Meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have been stalking a bit one of my colleagues so that she would answer 4 of my e-mails that were asking her how our ongoing project was going forward.

Two weeks after, she sends me an e-mail update where I believe she was a bit pissed off... She started by writing the following :

> Hi "MopMop",
>
> I hope all’s well, and absolutely. We have an [...] project ongoing and budget to plan.

I wanted to know what she meant by the "and absolutely". I really have issues communicating with that women [see other post here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104975/if-you-can-send-through-some-more-time-that-d-be-great) and I would like to know if she told me that because she is annoyed of my behavior or it is just an expression that I oviously don't get..

Comment: Sounds like she left something out, or perhaps is not a coherent writer. More likely she is affirming something that you said in your email, making the reference not obvious unless you have the text of that email at hand.

Comment: I don't see what she could be reffering to as I was just requesting a meeting to get more information about the projects advancement

Comment: Then it sounds like she "absolutely" agrees to the meeting.

Comment: It is normal to talk like that ? I mean she is not making any effort towards me not being a native speaker...

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would put her failure to communicate down to carelessness and lack of time. Emails are not formal writing, more like conversation in text. In conversation, we use a practice known as "conversational deletion"—reducing syntax to the bare minimum to convey meaning.

Since you say you were requesting a meeting to get more information, her "absolutely" probably means that she "absolutely" agrees to the meeting.

Imagine you were speaking to her in person. The conversation would probably go something like this:

> **YOU**: How are you doing?
>     **SHE**: Pretty good. I hope all is well with you.
>   **YOU**: Hey, can we have a meeting so I can get more information about the project's advancement.
>   **SHE**: Absolutely.

In that exchange the pleasantries are exchanged first and then the business at hand is discussed. In the email version, however, that would require multiple emails, so she is compressing those things together in one line.

> <sup>1</sup> I hope all’s well, <sup>2</sup> and absolutely. <sup>3</sup> We have an [...] project ongoing and budget to plan.

[1] is just a pleasantry because she doesn't want to be too abrupt.

[2] is the meat of the business response, acceding to your request.

[3] This is further information. It's not clear whether this is germane to the discussion or not, but she apparently wants you to be aware of it in either case.

The important thing to remember is that you should parse email responses more as conversation than expository writing. That may help you to interpret them better.